# Slim Framework PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello so I am using slim framework and decided to use PDO and here is my current code:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcgovernment_website', 'root', '');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
    $app->render('index.html');
});

$app->get('/template', function () use ($app) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcgovernment_website', 'root', '');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
    $app->render('template.html');
});
```

as you can see from the code, I keep repeating the connection in every `$app`. Is there a way to only call a single line in every `$app` so I won't have to keep repeating the database connection code? Thank you.

Comment: yea put it in a file and include it or autoload it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Slim Framework, but you can pass along multiple variables (declared outside the scope) into your `use`.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app, $dbh) { }
```